# Windows 10: how to prevent switching or closing an application

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-store-apps, windows-10

I'm developing an app for a Windows 10 device. This device will be exposed to users in a public place and its hardware buttons will be inaccessible.
How can I prevent a user from closing my application using touchscreen gestures?

Comment: You did not specify a programming language, but in any language that works with GUI there is usually a way to override `OnClose` event, and prevent the code from closing the window. Also, search the net for "kiosk mode".

Comment: @Dialecticus C# + xaml. Or I might consider the possibility of developing a web application and then use Internet Explorer / Edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up your application with Assigned Access:
http://www.winbeta.org/news/setup-assigned-access-windows-10-kiosk-mode

This will allow you to have your application launched as soon as the user is logged and nobody will be able to exit/close/switch the app.