# Run WindForms app as admin from Windows Scheduler for all users

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking way to run WinForms (GUI) app for all PC users 
App icon should sit in tray and display some info for logged user once clicked.

But user **should not be able to close it** (including killing task from windows task manager)

Initially I thought it should be sufficient to create local admin entry in Windows task scheduler which will start app for every user. But then I learned this way I cant really display GUI / run interactive app (can do console app but GUI is not displayed).

Can someone please advise what would be easiest way approach to achieve that ?

Only solution came to my mind at this moment was to create client-server app. Server run as service / console for admin, and client -> user gui. But still user can close client app ...

Comment: Your question is quite broad. What have you tried so far? Where can we find the reproducible sample?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10: how to prevent switching or closing an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414267/windows-10-how-to-prevent-switching-or-closing-an-application)

Comment: @oleksa - not really same case. Given link describes mobile app, also I would like start task as local admin, not logged user - just wanted user to interact with GUI app ran in admin context

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski - I thought Ive described what Ive tried and what difficulties were seen. Code doesnt really matter it can bi simple app with button on it displaying "hello word". As said above key question is how to run single instance as local admin, but allow user to interact with that.
(Especially in case of W10 - where this OS tend to keep logged multiple user after eg reboot)

Comment: You can try to use windows service for that and allow interaction with desktop

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski - but how to do that - do you have any links / examples ?
I did some try but I coudnt  make service to interact with desktop (on W10)

Comment: You can enable it in services config (if service run under local system account). Another option is to try to run it using task scheduler. But I don't know how to prevent closing of it

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski  - thanks. I can migrate to services if this allows me to start GUI app and will prevent service to be closed by regular user (no admin rights). Will experiment and get back feedback here. As Im not really services expert Id also appreciate if someone can share any examples / articles how to deal with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all for advices

Ive googled a lot and realized that **windows service interaction with desktop** is no longer possible in newer Windows versions (Vista +).

Read tons of arts saying there is no option to start GUI app via service...
Then I've finally found below post, which helped me archive what I needed

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite

Leaving for someone who was searching the same...